# How to prevent users from accessing restricted pages after the session expires? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, form-authentication

I have created a asp.net website with form authentication. The issue is when the session expires, and if I clicked on a page that only the Admins can view, the user still can see the website rather than redirecting to the login page. This only happens when the session expires automatically. If I logout manually and then try to access the restricted page, then I'm asked to log in. Any help given is greatly appreciated.

Web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" name="MyCustomAuthentication" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="2"/>
```

Web.config to restrict the user

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin" />
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

I also have this on the page_load in Login page

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
            // This is an unauthorized, authenticated request...
            Response.Redirect("~/Unauthorized.aspx");
    }

    lblMessage.Text = "";

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    GlobalVariables.GlobalFullName = string.Empty;
```

Comment: if(Session["YourSession"]==null || Convert.ToString(Session["YourSession"])==""){Response.Redirect("~/Unauthorized.aspx");} . @user6648535 try This one

Comment: @Faraz you mean add this to page_load in Login page?

Comment: No add this on Ristricted pages when you wanna prevent users access in page_load

Comment: I have the login in my Default.aspx. When I use this there it does not work as it is preventing me from login. Because on the page_load obviously the session is empty before I log in

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, but is there any other way to control this in one page. Otherwise if I have 10 pages, I need to add this in every page_load event on those 10 pages :(